# How to build iOS7 Style Audio Recorder App

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder, audiorecord

I am trying to build an audio recorder app similar to iOS7 built in one and looking for guidance on what controls to use for the recording app. I understand I will be using a tableview for the list of previous recordings and a UIView for the top recording view and on tapping record adjust the table view and move down the black recording view.

How should I implement the endless horizontal scrolling view? Should I use a collection view and keep adding elements to the model array as the time increments. Also what should I use for the timer. Is there something like setInterval for Objective C like in Javascript that I can use to keep updating the UI at regular time interval?

If someone also knows of a cocoa pod or sample code that would be greatly appreciated.

[image: iOS7 Audio Recorder]

Comment: The silence is deafening

Comment: I'm interested as well, but it's a pretty large ambiguous question. I would start a bounty on the question

Answer (score 2):

For recording the simplest audiorecorder is AVAudioRecorder. Here is a simple implementation of an audio recording app: https://github.com/calmez/Recorder. AVAudioRecorder has simple metering methods where you can read volume output of the channels

Honestly though, Apple would probably use CoreAudio to get the audio because it is more optimized. Novocaine is a good core audio engine that could get you started https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine

For rendering the waveform, I would guess that Apple probably uses OpenGL. I don't see how to do it easily and efficiently otherwise. You could draw them using the standard drawing APIs for UIView like this project does (https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView) but I don't see this animating well.

For the timer, there is NSTimer